# Image of $S^* = (0,1] \times [0, 2 \pi)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$T(r, \theta) = (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$$
I work out the mappings from the given rectangle to obtain a unit circle including the x-axis greater than $0$ but not including the origin, but the answer says that it's a unit disk excluding the origin. Where is the mapping that includes everything else in the circle?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Which mapping ? What do you mean by unit circle including the $x>0$ ?

Comment: If you draw a unit circle on graphing paper, also draw a straight, horizontal line from the origin to the coordinate $(1,0)$ but don't include the origin.

Comment: Sorry, this is just beyond my abilities.

Comment: @PandaBear i think OP wants to consider $T: (0,1] \times [0, 2 \pi ) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $T(r, \theta) = (rcos\theta, rsen\theta)$ and see what the image of $T$ is...?

Comment: If by "unit circle" you mean not just the boundary but also the interior, then "unit circle not including the origin" would be the same thing as "unit disk excluding the origin".

Comment: I only get the boundary.